# PostgreSQL: Unable to upsert (on conflict update) column that is camel case

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.app_banking_bankingdetail (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "sfAttachmentID" varchar(18) NOT NULL,
    created timestamptz NOT NULL,
    account_id int4 NOT NULL,
    opportunity_id int4 NOT NULL,
    "cashFlowLenders" int4 NULL,
    "saccLoans" int4 NULL,
    "cashFlowLendersInitvalue" int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT app_banking_bankingdetail_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT "app_banking_bankingdetail_sfAttachmentID_key" UNIQUE ("sfAttachmentID"),
    CONSTRAINT app_banking_bankingd_account_id_1c6512f0_fk_app_banki FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES public.app_banking_accountdetail(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    CONSTRAINT app_banking_bankingd_opportunity_id_975678c4_fk_app_banki FOREIGN KEY (opportunity_id) REFERENCES public.app_banking_opportunitydetail(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
CREATE INDEX app_banking_bankingdetail_account_id_1c6512f0 ON public.app_banking_bankingdetail USING btree (account_id);
CREATE INDEX app_banking_bankingdetail_opportunity_id_975678c4 ON public.app_banking_bankingdetail USING btree (opportunity_id);
CREATE INDEX "app_banking_bankingdetail_sfAttachmentID_46bede79_like" ON public.app_banking_bankingdetail USING btree ("sfAttachmentID" varchar_pattern_ops);
```

I am trying to do an upsert. However, I keep getting the error I believe is due to a column been CamelCase (This table is already in production).

When I run the following command, it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO app_banking_bankingdetail ("id", "account_id", "opportunity_id", "sfAttachmentID", "created") 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'asv1234', '2021-06-30T03:22:52.602383Z'),
    (2, 2, 2, 'asv1235', '2021-06-30T03:25:02.463398Z') 
ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET 
("account_id", "opportunity_id", "created") = (EXCLUDED.account_id, EXCLUDED.opportunity_id, EXCLUDED.created);

Updated Rows    2
```

But if I try to add the field sfAttachmentID:

```
INSERT INTO app_banking_bankingdetail ("id", "account_id", "opportunity_id", "sfAttachmentID", "created") 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'asv1234', '2021-06-30T03:22:52.602383Z'),
    (2, 2, 2, 'asv1235', '2021-06-30T03:25:02.463398Z') 
ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET 
("account_id", "opportunity_id","sfAttachmentID", "created") = (EXCLUDED.account_id, EXCLUDED.opportunity_id, EXCLUDED.sfAttachmentID, EXCLUDED.created);
```

I get the error:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column excluded.sfattachmentid does not exist
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "excluded.sfAttachmentID".
Position: 379
```

I have also try a few variations like

```
INSERT INTO app_banking_bankingdetail ("id", "account_id", "opportunity_id", "sfAttachmentID", "created") 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'asv1234', '2021-06-30T03:22:52.602383Z'),
    (2, 2, 2, 'asv1235', '2021-06-30T03:25:02.463398Z') 
ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET 
("account_id", "opportunity_id","sfAttachmentID", "created") = (EXCLUDED.account_id, EXCLUDED.opportunity_id, "EXCLUDED.sfAttachmentID", EXCLUDED.created);
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "EXCLUDED.sfAttachmentID" does not exist
Position: 379
```

and

```
INSERT INTO app_banking_bankingdetail ("id", "account_id", "opportunity_id", "sfAttachmentID", "created") 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'asv1234', '2021-06-30T03:22:52.602383Z'),
    (2, 2, 2, 'asv1235', '2021-06-30T03:25:02.463398Z') 
ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET 
("account_id", "opportunity_id","sfAttachmentID", "created") = ("EXCLUDED.account_id", "EXCLUDED.opportunity_id", "EXCLUDED.sfAttachmentID", "EXCLUDED.created");
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "EXCLUDED.account_id" does not exist
Position: 333
```

How can I specify the desire field in the conflict section?

Comment: Those dreaded quoted identifiers are [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) anyway. You might want to consider renaming those columns to avoid all those troubles with them

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hard lesson learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXCLUDED`  is a keyword and must not be quoted, you only need to quote the column name, not the whole expression.

```
INSERT INTO app_banking_bankingdetail ("id", "account_id", "opportunity_id", "sfAttachmentID", "created") 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 1, 'asv1234', '2021-06-30T03:22:52.602383Z'),
    (2, 2, 2, 'asv1235', '2021-06-30T03:25:02.463398Z') 
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE SET 
("account_id", "opportunity_id", "sfAttachmentID", "created") 
   = (EXCLUDED."account_id", EXCLUDED."opportunity_id", EXCLUDED."sfAttachmentID", EXCLUDED."created");
```